# Maven jar plugin - Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: java, maven, plugins, teamcity

I'm trying to run my Selenium tests through Teamcity on another server. The project starts compiling, but there's an error with maven.jar.plugin.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.112.215] failed
```

Originally, I had version 2.4 there, but then changed it to this one to try, and it failed as well. So, neither worked.

Of course, if I run my tests manually - locally, everything works fine.

I run the tests by calling mvn clean verify

I'd appreciate any help, let me know if you need more info.

Here's the plugin from my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: your maven seems not set up properly on the server. i guess the artefactory info is wrong or missing

Comment: @DebanjanB, I'm running Selenium tests, so I figured there has to be another person who came across a similar problem. I can remove the tag..

HenningLuther, how do I check/fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are running behind your company proxy. If yes then you may need to add your organization's proxy settings in settings.xml.

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>SOME ID</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>PROXY_HOST</host>
      <port>PROXY_PORT</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Comment: Perfect, this indeed was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different maven repository - in your maven settings.xml - put http://central.maven.org/maven2/ - which definitely has mentioned [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.1.0/maven-jar-plugin-3.1.0.pom)